# draw connection between two points with 2 given vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

i want to draw a connection between two points with 2 given lengths. Here is a sketch — maybe you understand.

[Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl84n.png)

Given are the points p1;p2…pn, the lengths of a and b and the point x1. I need a function that describes the angles of α and β.

I know there will be no answers when the distance between x1 and pn > lengths of a + b.

Thank you very much.

Regards Karl

Comment: Setting aside the multiple points $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$, let's deal with a single point $y$ that you want to "reach" from point $x$ using segments of length $a$ and $b$.  You are essentially describing a triangle whose sides are known, the two given lengths $a,b$ and the distance from $x$ to $y$.  There may be more than one solution, but the triangles involved will be *congruent*.

Comment: I just came up with another idea – but didnt get it any further. You can think of two circles crossing each other – each with radius a and b. yes their will be two solutions... Circle a with center on p and circle b with the center on x1.

Comment: Right.  The angles you want can be found by determining those two points of intersection (or one point, in the case the two circles are tangent to each other).